# Weblogic ConnectionFactory Lookup from Java Client

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I'm trying to enqueue a message on a jms queue (weblogic) from a java application.

```
InitialContext ctx = getInitialContext();
qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory)ctx.lookup("jms.bfred1cf");
qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();
qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("jms.bfred1queue");

private static InitialContext getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://soabpm-vm:7001/");
    return new InitialContext(env);
}
```

When i invoke the getInitalContext() methos it works fine. I got the context.
But when trying to get the connection factory, using the context, it gives the following error:

```
 <Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:      weblogic.rmi.internal.RMIEnvironment.getProperties(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Hashtable;
at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.getRMIClientTimeout(ResponseImpl.java:281)
at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.<init>(ResponseImpl.java:42)
at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevOutputStream.sendRecv(MsgAbbrevOutputStream.java:404)
at weblogic.rjvm.BasicOutboundRequest.sendReceive(BasicOutboundRequest.java:109)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:345)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_1035_WLStub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:423)
at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
at demo.Demo.main(Unknown Source)
```

Looking into Weblogic console, JNDI Tree I've the following:

JMS:

- ConnectionFactory:
       name: bfred1cf 
       className: weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteObjec 
       Binding Name: jms.bfred1cf
       Class: weblogic.jms.client.JMSXAConnectionFactory
- Queue
       name: bfred1queue
       className: weblogic.jms.common.WrappedDestinationImpl 
       Binding Name: jms.bfred1queue
       Class: weblogic.jms.common.DestinationImpl

If i try to enqueue a message from a SOA Suite project (BPEL) with a JMS Adapter, using the Outbound Conection Pool 
(eis/jms/bfre1) configured for the CF it works fine.

Does anyone have an idea about what can cause this error?

Thanks,
Fabio

Comment: It's almost like your client or server isn't using the correct version of the weblogic.jar file in its classpath. Something about the signatures for the API isn't matching up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

wlthint3client.jar

instead of wlclient.jar and wljmsclient.jar